# Mockito error with method that returns Optional<T>

Tags: java, mockito, option-type

I have an interface with the following method

```
public interface IRemoteStore {

    <T> Optional<T> get(String cacheName, String key, String ... rest);

}
```

The instance of the class implementing the interface is called remoteStore.

When I mock this with mockito and use the method when:

```
Mockito.when(remoteStore.get("a", "b")).thenReturn("lol");
```

I get the error:

> Cannot resolved the method `thenReturn(java.lang.String)`

I thought it has to do with the fact that get returns an instance of the Optional class so I tried this:

```
Mockito.<Optional<String>>when(remoteStore.get("cache-name", "cache-key")).thenReturn
        (Optional.of("lol"));
```

But, I get this error instead:

> when (`Optional<String>`) in Mockito cannot be applied to (`Optional<Object>`).

The only time it worked was with this:

```
String returnCacheValueString = "lol";
Optional<Object> returnCacheValue = Optional.of((Object) returnCacheValueString);
Mockito.<Optional<Object>>when(remotestore.get("cache-name", "cache-key")).thenReturn(returnCacheValue);
```

But above returns an instance of `Optional<Object>` and not `Optional<String>`.

Why couldn't I just return an instance of `Optional<String>` directly? If I could, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: Aren't you missing a bracket in the first code chunk?

Comment: Also FYI, don't confuse `java.util.Optional` with `com.google.common.base.Optional`, as the latter needs to be imported here.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Mocks that return have the expectation that the return type matches the mocked object's return type.

Here's the mistake:

```
Mockito.when(remoteStore.get("a", "b")).thenReturn("lol");
```

`"lol"` isn't an `Optional<String>`, so it won't accept that as a valid return value.

The reason it worked when you did

```
Optional<Object> returnCacheValue = Optional.of((Object) returnCacheValueString);
Mockito.<Optional<Object>>when(remotestore.get("cache-name", "cache-key")).thenReturn(returnCacheValue);
```

is due to `returnCacheValue` being an `Optional`.

This is easy to fix:  just change it to an `Optional.of("lol")` instead.

```
Mockito.when(remoteStore.get("a", "b")).thenReturn(Optional.of("lol"));
```

You can also do away with the type witnesses as well. The result above will be inferred to be `Optional<String>`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yeah, I realized the error and did change it. What was wrong was that I didn't set my project language level to java 8.

Comment: I wouldn't have known that from reading your question.  `Optional` is a class in Google Guava - a very popular third-party library - and it's compatible with Java 7.

Comment: This is great! Wish I could give more upvotes. `thenReturn(Optional.of("lol"));`

Comment: @Yu Lin Chen - Could you please guide me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135373/optional-cannot-be-returned-by-stream-in-mockito-test-classes ?

Comment: Thank you.
That okay, but I can't understand why we should use Optional.of in thenReturn??

Comment: @Makoto is there a way to mock directly `.get` call? something like `when(obj.getOptional().get()).thenReturn(someValue)`?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you are seeing errors, but this compiles/runs error-free for me:

```
public class RemoteStoreTest {
    public interface IRemoteStore {
        <T> Optional<T> get(String cacheName, String key);
    }
    public static class RemoteStore implements IRemoteStore {
        @Override
        public <T> Optional<T> get(String cacheName, String key) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        RemoteStore remoteStore = Mockito.mock(RemoteStore.class);

        Mockito.when( remoteStore.get("a", "b") ).thenReturn( Optional.of("lol") );
        Mockito.<Optional<Object>>when( remoteStore.get("b", "c") ).thenReturn( Optional.of("lol") );

        Optional<String> o1 = remoteStore.get("a", "b");
        Optional<Object> o2 = remoteStore.get("b", "c");

        Assert.assertEquals( "lol", o1.get() );
        Assert.assertEquals( "lol", o2.get() );
        Mockito.verify(remoteStore);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Don, thanks for the response. This made me realize that my IDE has the project language level set at java 7, not java 8. But I am using Optional from Guava, not Java 8 but that's a different question. Thank you.

Comment: Explaining *why* it works is better than saying that it does.  The OP may not be the only person that has this problem; others may come in and have a similar question in the future.