# Unit test java Optional with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to test a method which returns an Optional client in it.

I want to test the scenario when client is empty.This is not a working code but overall it looks like this

```
public Optional<String> doSomething(String place) {
    Optional<Client> client = Optional.empty();
    try {
        client = Optional.ofNullable(clientHelper.get(place));
    } catch (Ex ex) {
        log.warn("Exception occured:", ex);
    }
    return client.isPresent() ? Optional.ofNullable(client.get().getPlaceDetails(place)) : Optional.empty();
}
```

I have a helper class clientHelper which returns a client based on place if exists, if not it throws exception.
For test, this is what I came up with

```
  @Test
public void testClientHelper(){
    ClientHelper clientHelper =  Mockito.mock(ClientHelper.class);
    Optional<Client> client = Optional.empty();
    Mockito.when(Optional.ofNullable(clientHelper.get("IN"))).thenReturn(client);
    assertEquals( doSomething("IN"), Optional.empty())
}
```

But it returns exception -

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Optional cannot be returned by get()
get() should return Client
```

I have been following this link [Mockito error with method that returns Optional<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946167/mockito-error-with-method-that-returns-optionalt?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

your problem here is that you are calling `when` with something that isn't a mock. You are passing it an `Optional`.

If I understand what you are trying to do here, the clientHelper is passed to the object with the `doSomething` method and you want to mock it for testing purposes. If that's the case it'd more typically look like this:

```
interface ClientHelper {
    Client get(String place) throws Ex;
}

class ClassUnderTest {
    private final ClientHelper clientHelper;

    public ClassUnderTest(ClientHelper helper) {
        this.clientHelper = helper;
    }

    public Optional<String> doSomething(String place) {
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(clientHelper.get(place).getPlaceDetails(place));
        } catch (Ex ex) {
            log.warn("Exception: " + ex);
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}

@Test
void testFullHelper() {
    Client client = mock(Client.class);
    when(client.getPlaceDetails("IN")).thenReturn("Details");
    ClientHelper helper = mock(ClientHelper.class);
    when(helper.get("IN")).thenReturn(client);
    ClassUnderTest obj = new ClassUnderTest(helper);
    assertEquals("Details", obj.doSomething("IN"));
}
```